# How to add mutiple users on same session where game will be played?

Tags: php, angularjs, session-storage

It's Scrum Poker game having fibbonacci series.Every game has unique session.

I have to add multiple users on the same session.

Users will only get game session link via mail and all anonymous users will be in the same game session after login with name.

As the user selects card,its value store in session.Same selected value will be send to admin in unflipped manner.

So I need to know what user selected during game and where it will be stored. As every user has their own machine, I can't use session storage.

I am using `angularjs`, `PHP` and `mysql`. Does anyone has any idea of how to do this? How will I get to know what value user has voted during the game?

Comment: Large chunks of text are difficult to read when language is badly used and, often, technical. I formatted your text to have a lighter structure, and made some corrections in the expressions you were using. More importantly is that you put in your tags the technologies you are using. I do think your question is poor and urge you to consider adding more relevant information about your attempts and structure for your own session.

Comment: Thank you. I'll update my question.